# Mary has 14 female and 10 male friends. Half of Mary's friends are older than her. What's the probability (male friend OR older friend calls)?

Tags: probability

- Mary has 24 friends
- 12 of her friends are older than her

Probability of calling:

> P(male) = 10/24
>
> P(female) = 14/24
>
> P(older friend (both male and female)) = 12/24

I'm looking for:

> P(male OR older friend) = P(male) + P(older friend) - P(male ∩ older friend)

---

I don't know how to find an intersection of 'male' and 'older friend'

> P(male ∩ older friend)

---

EDIT: Additional question, can we use this??

> 10/24 = 0.416 = male
>
> 14/24 = 0.583 = female

If we use those numbers to split number 12 (amount of older friends), we get:

> 12*0.416 = 5 older males = |male ∩ older friend|
>
> 12*0.583 = 7 older females = |female ∩ older friend|

---

EDIT 2: Possible solution

If we assume that there are 5 older males we can proceed

> P(male OR older friend) = P(male) + P(older friend) - P(male ∩ older friend)
>
> P(male OR older friend) = 10/24 + 12/24 - 5/24 = 17/24

Comment: It isn't determined.  Perhaps they want you to assume that age and gender are independent, so then the answer would be $5$.  But that would just be a guess.

Comment: There's not enough information. Since the number of older friends is larger than the number of male friends, any number of male friends could be older.

Comment: It's a poorly framed question..But if assume half to mean five...then intersection probability is $5/24$

Comment: @user35508: Who says that it's not all 10 male friends (and 2 of the female friends) that are older? Or _none_ of the male friends (but 12 of the female friends)?

Comment: Also, there seems to be no assumption that each of the 24 friends is equally likely to be calling Mary. If one of them is her boyfriend, he is probably significantly more likely to call her than a remoter acquaintance would be. She might also have a girlfriend, of course, but that is statistically less likely, by some unknown amount that is culturally dependent.

Comment: Check the edit once again please, the solution seems to be 17/24. I found this task in a book. The solution in the book checks out with mine.