# Two people are hitting the target. Probability of target being hit only once =?

Tags: probability

> P (Person A hits the target) = 0.8
>
> P (Person B hits the target) = 0.4
>
> P (Target is hit only once) = ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Note:  as with [your prior question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183456/mary-has-14-female-and-10-male-friends-half-of-marys-friends-are-older-than-he), this can not be answered without making some assumption about independence.  In this case, though, I think that guessing that the two shooters act independently is fairly reasonable.

Comment: I know that probability of target being hit is 0.88, based on P(A) + P(B) - P(A∩B)...0.8 + 0.4 - (0.8*0.4) = 0.88

Comment: What is the probability that only $A$ hits?  What is the probability that only $B$ hits?

Answer (score 1):

This is $P \left( (A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B) \right) = P(A) + P(B) - 2 P(A \cap B) = 0.56$.